# shell test always exit

Tags: shell, conditional-statements, exit

I'm begginner on shell, currently i wrote a small script and i got a problem without any error :/

This code always exit my script and i dont understand why :

```
[[ -x $PATH ]] || log_failure_msg "Binary file not found or not executable!"; exit 0
```

When $PATH is valid i got nothing and if the path is wrong i got my failure message.

If i remove `log_failure_msg "Binary file not found or not executable!";` the script work perfectly -_-

Ho i can solve this problem without if/fi conditions?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is precedence, as explained by phlogratos. However, you can't use parenthesis as they spawn a sub-shell and you'll be exiting *that* shell. For this particular issue, curly braces exist. They have almost the same semantics but they spawn jobs in the *current* shell.

```
$ cat a.sh 
[[ -f file ]] || { echo error; exit 0; }
echo "ok"
$ touch file
$ ./a.sh 
ok
$ rm file 
$ ./a.sh 
error
$
```

Answer (score -1):

```
[[ -x $PATH ]] || log_failure_msg "Binary file not found or not executable!"; exit 0
```

is equivalent to

```
{ [[ -x $PATH ]] || log_failure_msg "Binary file not found or not executable!" } ; exit 0
```

What you need is

```
[[ -x $PATH ]] || { log_failure_msg "Binary file not found or not executable!"; exit 0 }
```

I'm assuming you are using bash. The bash man page states:

```
..., && and || have equal precedence, followed by ; and &, which have equal precedence.
```